# Como passar valor de input via post no asp.net core razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

Gostaria de saber como passar o valor digitado em um input para um método Post na PageModel.

No cshtml:

```cshtml
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label asp-for="Tickets.Identificador" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Tickets.Identificador" class="form-control" id="txtBusca"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="Tickets.Identificador" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" asp-route-id="Tickets.Identificador" value="Localizar" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="margin-top:5px;" />
</div>
```

Na PageModel:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync( string id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    var item = _context.Tickets.Where(m => m.Identificador == id).First();

    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

Comment: Você não está utilizando nenhum método assíncrono, prefira utilizar `public IActionResult OnPost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu input coloque a propriedade (name) com o mesmo nome do parâmetro recebido na sua action. Aqui é um exemplo no [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pMOqKk)

```
 <input asp-for="Tickets.Identificador" class="form-control" name="id" id="txtBusca"/>
```

Comment: E o type="submit" ?

Comment: O type="submit" é no botão para enviar o formulário para o servidor.

Comment: Valeu funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Que bom! Editei a resposta e inclui um exemplo online caso ainda tenha alguma dúvida. Att.

Answer (score 0):

No envio de uma solicitação POST, GET, etc. Você deve nomear o input com o nome do parâmetro ou propriedade. Por exemplo:

```html
<form method="post">
    <input name="id" />
    <input name="example" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

E então poderá pegar os valores da seguinte maneira:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPost(int id, string example)
{
    // ....
}
```

Ou usando o atributo `BindProperty`:

```cs
[BindProperty]
public int Id { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public string Example { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    // ...
}
```

Caso queira utilizar o atributo `BindProperty` também com solicitações do tipo **GET**, deve atribuir o parâmetro `SupportsGet` com `true`:

```cs
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Também pode atribuir um objeto usando `.` (ponto), da seguinte maneira:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <input name="Person.Name" />
    <input name="Person.Surname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

E então poderá pegar os valores da seguinte maneira:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPost(Person person)
{
    // ....
}
```

Ou ainda usando o atributo `BindProperty`:

```cs
[BindProperty]
public Person Person { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    // ...
}
```

Como a propriedade está na `PageModel` você pode usar o atributo `asp-for`:

```cshtml
<input asp-for="Person.Name" />
```

> **Obs:** O que importa é o nome das propriedades e parâmetros, e não seu tipo. Ou seja você poderia ter um parâmetro do tipo `Person` com o nome `user`, e então no input utilizaria assim: `<input name="user.Name" />`.

Aparentemente você tem uma propriedade `Tickets` na sua `PageModel`. Se tiver você pode adicionar o atributo `[BindProperty]` para ela, que todos os valores correspondentes da solicitação POST serão atribuídos e então poderia utilizar dessa maneira:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    // Agora você pode usar "Tickets.Identificador" ao invés de "id".
    var item = _context.Tickets.Where(m => m.Identificador == Tickets.Identificador).First();

    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

Caso tenha, mas ela já está atribuída, ou tem outro propósito, você deve nomear o input com o nome do parâmetro ou propriedade, que no seu caso é `id`:

```html
<input asp-for="Tickets.Identificador" class="form-control" name="id" id="txtBusca" />
```

Comment: Valeu Vinícius Lima, obrigado pelas dicas.